# How to subtract these two dates? How to count the number of minutes between them?

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

```
when_start = models.DateTimeField()
when_end = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I get the difference in minutes between `when_start` and `when_end`?

```
my_minutes = when_end - when_start = #number of minutes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subtract, you are going to get something like this:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 5, 41038)
```

To convert it to minutes:

```
minutes = (when_end - when_start).total_seconds()/60
```

Comment: Thx. I have this error: `'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_secounds'`

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
my_minutes = (when_end - when_start).total_seconds() / 60
```